# compiling tcltls .so with static openssl-Lib

Tags: openssl, tcl, static-linking, activetcl

I need to compile tcl/tk myself and want to add the tcltls-Package. 
As i don't want to depend on the systems openssl-lib i want to include openssl into my shared-object.

Therefore i installed openssl-static on the system and compiled tcl / tcltls.
I tried also "./configure --enable-static-ssl" but tcltls always links to the system libs:

> ldd tcltls.so
>          linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xf77d2000)
>          libdl.so.2 => /lib/libdl.so.2 (0xf77b8000)
>     libresolv.so.2 => /lib/libresolv.so.2 (0xf779e000)
>     libssl.so.10 => /usr/lib/libssl.so.10 (0xf7735000)
>     libcrypto.so.10 => /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.10 (0xf756a000)
>     libz.so.1 => /lib/libz.so.1 (0xf7555000)
>     libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /lib/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0xf7515000)
>     libkrb5.so.3 => /lib/libkrb5.so.3 (0xf7437000)
>     libcom_err.so.2 => /lib/libcom_err.so.2 (0xf7432000)
>     libk5crypto.so.3 => /lib/libk5crypto.so.3 (0xf7407000)
>     libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0xf7270000)
>     /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf77d3000)
>     libkrb5support.so.0 => /lib/libkrb5support.so.0 (0xf7263000)
>     libkeyutils.so.1 => /lib/libkeyutils.so.1 (0xf725f000)
>     libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0xf7244000)
>     libselinux.so.1 => /lib/libselinux.so.1 (0xf7225000)

I checked the ActiveState tcltls-Package and there exist no link to the system ssl (or crypto) lib:

> ldd tcltls.so
>     linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffdba8b9000)
>     libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f7f59e72000)
>     libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f7f59aa8000)
>     /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f7f5a47f000)

So, how do the ActiveState-Crew compile tcltls or which options do i have to set to get ssl linked static into my tcltls-shared-object-package?

Also the size of the shared object differs (of course):
My tcltls.so has about 380kB. The ActiveState tcltls.so 2,3MB

Using tcl8.6.8 + tcltls-1.7.16 on linux.

Thanks for any hints/ideas/help!
Matthias

Comment: Obvious counter-question: do you have a static `libssl.a` installed?

Comment: Yes. I think it comes wirth openssl-static:  -rw-r--r--. 1 root root 613464 22. Mär 2017  /usr/lib/libssl.a

Comment: Hello to everybody, any ideas? I still struggle with this issue...